# Basic browser authentication with Safari Capybara Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara, safaridriver

I've got a problem with browser authentication on Safari using Capybara/Selenium.

I'm using this code to authenticate:

```
visit "https://#{ENV['AUTH_USERNAME']}:#{ENV['AUTH_PASSWORD']}@my-staging-app.heroku.com"
```

This works just fine on Chrome and FF but not on Safari.

Any ideas how to bypass this?

Comment: How about add `page.driver.browser.authorize(username, password)` before `visit`?

Comment: Unfortunately no :( 
```*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `authorize' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Safari::Driver:0x00007f97409952f8>```

Comment: also I've just read that this feature(login via url) is deprecated due to security issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, I've found the solution for this. I had to use reversed proxy using e.g. Nginx and send proper headers :)

Here is how I've done it:

In this example I'll be using creds `login: admin` and `password: secret123`.

Go to https://www.base64encode.org and encode your creds `admin:secret123`.

In this example it's `YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0MTIz`

`brew install nginx`

`sudo vim /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Past there this code:

```
worker_processes  1;  

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name localhost;

        location / { 
            proxy_pass https://your_app.herokuapp.com;
            proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0MTIz";
        }   
    }   
}
```

Change `proxy_pass` to match your app url.

And `proxy_set_header` to `Authorization "Basic <your_encoded_creds>"`

Then: `brew services start nginx`

From now on, when you'll hit `http://localhost:8080` you'll be redirected to your page and logged in.

Comment: I have this configured as documented (except for my values for proxy_pass url and Authorization encoded password) and I still see the authentication dialog from the site when I go to localhost:8080. Any ideas why I would see that instead of being authenticated? If I use the same URL with the credentials included (https://<user:pwd>@... it works.  But Safari doesn't support that.