# How to handle basic url authentication using selenium in Safari browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

### In chrome below solution is working:

```
driver.get("https://username:password@something.com");
```

### In firefox below solution is working:

```
driver.get("https://username:password@something.com);
```

*and then:*

```
driver.get("http://something.com");
```

In safari both of the above solutions are not working. I have also tried with **Alert** class in selenium. Googled a lot, still did not find any solution working. Any solution which can be used across all browsers would be awesome ;), solution for safari alone is also fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try checking this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481441/basic-browser-authentication-with-safari-capybara-selenium)

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these approaches is expected to work; browsers have stopped accepting user:password for Basic Authentication, so it doesn't work under WebDriver control either. The WebDriver Working Group is aware of this functionality gap but hasn't proposed a solution yet :(